# CSS problems. How do I move two elements to the right and keep them in different blocks?

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
div class="plan-again-text">
  Didn't find the perfect trip? Let's plan again.
</div>

<div class="plan-again">
  <%= link_to "Let's Plan Again.", new_planner_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.plan-again {
  margin-right: 30px;
  a {
    color: #861a08
  }
}

.plan-again-text {
  font-family: 'IM Fell Great Primer', serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

So if I use float right on both... they wind up being on the same line which I think makes sense. What I want is for them both to be on the right side of my page and on top of each other. Is there anyway else besides doing like adding

```
margin 400px?
```

to my css?

Comment: That's not plain CSS and you should post the actual rendered HTML, not whatever that language that is that starts with `<%`

Answer (score 1):

Use both `float:right` and [**`clear:both`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear):

```css
.plan-again-text, .plan-again {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  font: 15px verdana;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="plan-again-text">
  Didn't find the perfect trip? Let's plan again.
</div>

<div class="plan-again">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Comment: Does that css apply to both classes? Is that what the comma does?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `.clearfix` class to help keep them on the same line.  You could keep your current LESS file, and just add a new class with the following styles:

```
.clearfix {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Then add this div into your markup here:

```
<div class="plan-again-text">
  Didn't find the perfect trip? Let's plan again.
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="plan-again">
  <%= link_to "Let's Plan Again.", new_planner_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

You can look into Bootstrap's clearfix here, and even implement their LESS mixin.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix

I wrote this little info page a while back for some co-workers helping to explain clears and floats.  Perhaps you might find it useful.

http://robabby.github.io/lunch-and-learn/clear-float.html